# MIME Type for numerical arrays?

Tags: http, mime

I am thinking about an application which will use HTTP to transfer blocks of numbers with data types like "network-endian, signed 32-bit integer" or "ieee binary64,network-endian" etc.  For this application I (probably) want to put this type info in the HTTP headers rather than the message body.

This seems to be a job for Content-Type header, but I know of no standard MIME types for this sort of thing.  Are there any?  If not, what is the best option?  Invent a content-type? Invent a new HTTP header?  Put it in the message body after all?

Comment: Sounds to me like "put it in the body after all".  The body can easily be a format of your own without messing with and/or overriding the HTTP headers.  Let HTTP take care of itself and use the body for your own data.  The body can easily have a headers-and-body format of its own; so you'd send HTTP headers, followed by an empty line and your own headers, followed by your data.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a header, the field name of the header defines its content, not the Content-Type; they should be completely separable. I.e., a Content-Type that has a particular relationship to / requirement for a header is a protocol design smell.

I'd put it in the message body and mint a new media type -- but only after having a really long, hard look at the current options, of which there are many. Formats are hard.

Comment: Can you clarify your first paragraph?  I want meta-data to describe what type of information is in the body.  That is *exactly* what Content-Type is for.  Even if I shouldn't use it for other reasons.  On the other hand, I am very reluctant to to "mint a new media type", because my actual goal is to invent a simple network protocol (in this application transferring numbers is essential; transport over HTTP is gravy).

Comment: I read your question as wanting to put the data in the headers, not the body. If you want to put the data in the body, have a look at JSON, BSON, Thrift, ProtoBuffers, etc. etc. etc.